# How to deploy a war file from azure container blob onto the app service in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a sample.war file in terraform. I want to deploy the war file onto azure app service through terraform without using Azure CLI.
The code I have

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
        source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "~>3.56"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "MyRG"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_plan" {
  name                = "Plan1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "sttg2023"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example1" {
  name                  = "content"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "blob"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "sample.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example1.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "C:/Terraform/sample.war"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app_name" {
  name                = "AppStart2023"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.app_plan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.app_plan.id

  site_config {
    always_on = true
    application_stack {
      java_version = 8
      java_server = "TOMCAT"
      java_server_version = 9
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    WEBSITES_PORT = 8080
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az webapp deploy
        --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}
        --name ${azurerm_linux_webapp.app_name.name}
        --src-url ${azurerm_storage_blob.blobexample.url}
    EOT
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with azurerm_linux_web_app.app_name,
│   on main.tf line 104, in resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app_name":
│  104:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command 'az webapp deploy
│   --resource-group MyRG
│   --ids "/subscriptions/5c46537d-eb01-4e78-92e4-098236cb8f15/resourceGroups/MyRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/AppStart2023"
│   --name AppStart2023
│   --src-url https://sttg2023.blob.core.windows.net/content/sample.war
│ ': exit status 1. Output: ERROR: (--resource-group --name | --ids) are required
```

Then I gave the ids

```
     provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az webapp deploy
        --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}
        --ids "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/resourceGroups/MyRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/AppStart2023"
        --name AppStart2023
        --src-url ${azurerm_storage_blob.blobexample.url}
    EOT
  }
```

I am getting the same error again.
Can someone please help me with the code to deploy the sample.war file from container blob onto app service.
Also I have my sample.war file in my local azure shell storage. Instead of deploying from container can anyone help me with how to deploy the sample.war onto the azure appservice either from local azure shell storage or from container blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also received the same error when I tried in my environment.

```
Output: ERROR: (--resource-group --name | --ids) are required
│ /bin/sh: line 2: --resource-group: command not found
│ /bin/sh: line 3: --name: command not found
│ /bin/sh: line 4: --src-url: command not found
```

I found the line and the cause of the error after analyzing the code. When using the `az webapp deploy` command, you must pass all parameters on the same line rather than on the next. It fails to identify the inputs provided in the code because it lacks a separator.

And, rather than uploading the `war` file from the local `C:` drive, I first uploaded it to the `Azure cloud shell` storage, as shown, and then provided the path under `source` property from the cloud shell directory.

[image]

*I modified your code as follows and was able to upload it onto the app service successfully.*

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "MyRG"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_plan" {
  name                = "Plan1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "sttg2023jahn"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example1" {
  name                  = "content"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "blob"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "sample.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example1.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "/home/xxxxx_rk/SampleWebApp.war"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app_name" {
  name                = "AppStart2023jahn"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.app_plan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.app_plan.id

  site_config {
    always_on = true
    application_stack {
      java_version = 8
      java_server = "TOMCAT"
      java_server_version = 9
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    WEBSITES_PORT = 8080
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az webapp deploy --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name} --name ${azurerm_linux_web_app.app_name.name} --ids ${azurerm_linux_web_app.app_name.id} --src-url ${azurerm_storage_blob.blobexample.url} --type war
    EOT
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Uploaded blob in the storage account container:***

[image]

Go to your deployed `App Service >> Advanced editor` under `Development Tools`. It redirects to the below page as shown.

[image]

Once it is opened, go to `Site/wwwroot` under `Browse Directory`. You can be able to view the deployed `war` file as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got that working. I have the container access type as private. In that case the terraform code is showing me bad request. Then how to I access my war file to deploy it onto the app service(with private blob).

Comment: Checking on it and let you know the update. @Lekha

Comment: You need to generate a SAS token to access a private blob temporarily. Use [`azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_account_blob_container_sas#sas) to proceed with that. @Lekha